# Mostrar el nombre de un archivo seleccionado con input file

Tags: php, html, css

Mi problema es que di formato a una etiqueta  de manera que lo oculte y uso una label para poder darle mejor apariencia, el inconveniente es que al ocultar el input ya no me muestra el nombre del archivo, quiero que se pueda ver el nombre al seleccionar para que el usuario vea que si selecciono algo.

```
                <input type="file" name="archivo" id="file">
                <label for="file">
                <span class="material-icons">
                plagiarism</span>
                &nbsp;
                Buscar archivo</label><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
            </form>
```

Este es el css

```
    display: none;
}
label{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    height: 60px;
    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 43%;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
label:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="submit"]{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 43%;
    color: #fff;
    background: green;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 250px;
}
.nom{
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar algo de javascript:

```js
function onLoadImage(files){
  console.log(files)
  if (files && files[0]) {
    document
      .getElementById('imgName')
      .innerHTML = files[0].name
  }
}
```

```css
#img{display:none}
label{padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 5px}
```

```html
<label for="img">Cargar imagen</label>
<input 
  id="img" 
  type="file" 
  onChange="onLoadImage(event.target.files)" />
<span id="imgName"></span>
```